# New Grails controller doesn't seem to respond

Tags: grails, groovy

Grails 2.3.6 here. I went into `myapp/grails-app/controllers` and manually added a new `WidgetController.groovy` class:

```
class WidgetController {
    def fizz() {
        redirect(url: "http://google.com")
    }
}
```

Then I run my Grails app locally, and when I go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/widget/fizz` I just get my custom "page does not exist" error page. No errors in the logs.

Note: I **did not** use the `grails create-controller Widget` command; I just added a new file manually. What is going on here and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a blank fizz.gsp page to your view/widget and it will work.

Comment: if this helps, is this a problem with grails 2.3.6?  the controller as it stands works with 2.4.3 out of the box.